# Eyes don't move with Rig

Tags: animation, armature, bones

So I'm modeling a character but the original model I used didn't have eyes, so I had to import those eyes.

I then joined the eyes with the model. The only problem is, when I pose my character, the eyes don't move with the rest of him. This doesn't make sense as they are joined and I can't individually select the eyes.

[image]

Comment: I edited your question, because this is Blender Stackexchange and not Dead Memes Stackexchange.

Comment: So after you've joined the eyes to the head, have you assigned this new part of the mesh to the head bone, in Properties panel > Data > Vertex Groups?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this before...

What you do is in editing mode, subdivide a bone so that one of its ends is the same as another. The ends that don't have adjacent bones will be used to control the eyes.
Make sure you keep the eye-controlling bones as children to the parent bone, which is linked to what controls the body. You only need the controlling bones to have any weight painted to them.

Answer (score 0):

I know two ways which can help:

It is possible to weight paint the eyes to vertex group of deform bone

It is possible to assign the eye vertices to a vertex group that is used in a deform bone which should control the eye (in the armature modifier it is possible to show pose in edit mode which makes this easier).